# How to output redirect to overwrite file while command is running Linux?

Tags: linux, pipe, output-redirect

I am not sure if this is even possible. But I am using this command to get network throughput.

```
ifstat -t -S -i wlan0
```

Run just like that it updates inline on the console but when I pipe it, it appends a new line to the file.

```
ifstat -t -S -i wlan0 >> /tmp/transfer.txt

  Time          wlan0
HH:MM:SS   KB/s in  KB/s out

21:33:35      4.27    201.47
21:33:36      4.20    178.88
21:33:37      4.41    190.76
21:33:38      4.32    186.61
21:33:39      5.07    177.42
21:33:40      4.15    182.87
21:33:41      5.70    180.93
21:33:42      4.21    194.71
21:33:43      3.80    181.35
21:33:44      3.86    185.57
21:33:45      3.92    189.78
21:33:46      4.08    195.29
etc...
```

OK I understand using this will overwrite the file.But only after I run it the first time.Not DURING the execution of the app.

```
ifstat -t -S -i wlan0 >> /tmp/transfer.txt
```

I really do not need to keep a log of all the transfer rates and only **interested in writing that one line** on every update while the application is running.  *Instead of appending lines during executions, I want it to create a new file or overwrite it every second.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically you're not piping, but redirecting output.

Looks like you want to use `>` instead of `>>`?

For obtaining just the last line **while** ifstat is executing you could extract it in a 2nd file like this:

```
while true; do tail -1 /tmp/transfer.txt > /tmp/transfer2.txt; sleep .5; done
```

To overwrite the file each time with out keeping a log.

```
while true; do ifstat -t -i wlan0 1 1 | tail -1 > /tmp/transfer.txt; sleep .5; done;
```

Comment: I need it to overwrite the file WHILE the command is running, not after each time I run that command.

Comment: That is also interesting but I really could do without keeping a log. can I do a tail on the output redirection?

Comment: Unfortunately not in a simple/shell-based way (that I know of) since the original ifstat cmd constantly produces output and tail will wait until the it completes to get to the last line. You could also pipe the ifstat cmd from @Atafar's response (i.e. multiple ifstat executions) to 'tail -1' before redirecting to /tmp/transfer.txt if don't want the 2nd logfile.

Comment: you can make if stat run for 1 second then it terminates,  Like Atafar did with the `1` on the end. But that doesn't overwrite the file if it exists, it just appends to it.

Comment: That's what I meant in the last phrase (and yes, it does overwrite): while true; do ifstat -t -i wlan0 1 | tail -1 > /tmp/transfer.txt; sleep .5; done

Comment: Side note: when reading the results be prepared with a retry since eventually you will read a truncated file due to overwriting, meaning an empty or incomplete line, maybe even a failure in opening the file.

Comment: Yea I understand the I/O blocking . OK, I see. This actually works, you missed a 1. `while true; do ifstat -t -i wlan0 1 1 | tail -1 > /tmp/transfer.txt; sleep .5; done;` The file is truncated quite often and I only see the results every now and again so there is serious I/O blocking going here. But I can modify this slightly to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following (I do not have your version of `ifstat`, so I cannot verify this on my own system).

```
while /bin/true; do ifstat -t -i wlan0 1 > tmp/transfer.txt; sleep 1; done
```

or perhaps just

```
ifstat -t -i wlan0 > tmp/transfer.txt
```

So, don't use the `-S` flag since this does not work when redirecting to file.

Comment: I need it to overwrite the file WHILE the command is running, not after each time I run that command

Comment: I see what you are doing. OK. Unfortunately  it doesn't work. It still appends to the file. strange? I am running this on Raspbian.If I use just the `>` manually it recreates the file. But not your one liner.The one liner only does it once after I run it. But I can work with this and make it do what I need! Thanks